# Implementation or enforcement: which is required by law by the governments concerned?

Tags: police, india, military, governmental-liability, government-officers

In this q/a site and also in other q/a site of stack exchange networks, numerous questions are asked and answered. If these questions and answers are found to be legally binding, do the governments concerned to take appropriate steps to enforce and implement what is required by law. What is the relationship between the stack exchange network and the governments concerned and how these two different realities are connected? Can their opinions go side by side? can the governments intervene where opinions are contradictory and if the governments feel cases are of gross injustice? one example of such cases is destroying important office papers with a torrent of invective which can make countless person's world upside down.

Answer (score 5):

### if these questions and answers are found to be legally binding ...

They aren’t. Therefore the premise of your question is flawed.

It’s like asking “If my dog was a cat ...”. Well, since your dog isn’t a cat we don’t need to hear the rest of the question.

Comment: -you have adequately answered my question.many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> what is the relationship between stack exchange network and the governments concerned and how these two different realities are connected?

Governments have and enforce their laws.

StackExchange takes care as to avoid breaking those laws. So far so good.

> if these questions and answers are found to be legally binding

They are not. [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) care of that.

Comment: @Greendrake-your answer is sufficient for  my query.many thanks.